# Wordpress each user has each content for a page,how to do that?

Tags: posts, users, content

I am a newer of PHP language,I have a project of user system,that need each user has each different content,I place the content to a page,when user login,open this page will display that content.To do that,I think may have these steps:

1. Get data from database for each user,like register date
2. There is already a page exist, no content.
3. Assign these data to a login user,set the data read from database to a page, display in that page Or update content to this empty page, so the user can see the new content.

Is that a plugin or several plugin can do that? I found an example from WordPress help:

```
    // Update post 37
  $my_post = array(
      'ID'           => 37,
      'post_title'   => 'This is the post title.',
      'post_content' => 'This is the updated content.',
  );

// Update the post into the database
  wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

It seems can update content by program, but where shall I put this code?(I am newer,sorry)

Answer (score 0):

WP-Members™ is a free membership management framework for WordPress® that restricts content to registered users.

[For reference please have a look](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-members/)

Comment: Thanks,do you know how to update the content with that code?